# rsyslog config to store only raw message ($msg) to a file

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

How can I store only the ***raw message*** to a file?
E.g.:
I received a message via **rsyslog**:

### Received syslog message:

```
May  4 13:18:47 xxxx apache-error: [Wed May 04 13:18:41.256596 2016] [:error] [pid 54583] [client 192.168.30.200:52638] script '/var/www/aaa.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I need a *rsyslog config* to extract raw message from input, **without syslog header** (highlighted bellow):

> May  4 13:18:47 xxxx apache-error: ***[Wed May 04 13:18:41.256596 2016]
>   [:error] [pid 54583] [client 192.168.30.200:52638] script
>   '/var/www/aaa.php' not found or unable to stat***

### expected Output:

```
[Wed May 04 13:18:41.256596 2016] [:error] [pid 54583] [client 192.168.30.200:52638] script '/var/www/aaa.php' not found or unable to stat
```

tnx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a custom template in a rsyslog config file.  So in `/etc/rsyslog.d`, find the config file that configures the log file in question.  If you're talking about syslog, then you can add a custom template and change the config line to something like:

```
$template myFormat,"%msg%\n"
*.*         -/var/log/syslog; myFormat
```

Also, if you want that template for all your log files, you can add this to your rsyslog config file, and thus you wouldn't have to add the template specifically to your log file line:

```
$template myFormat,"%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate myFormat
```

Comment: tnx @drewyupdrew, ur answer solved my problem.  
  Some useful links:
   http://itsol.biz/custom-templates-rsyslog/

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to use :
`$template myFormat,"%msg:2:2048%\n`

reference : http://rsyslog-users.1305293.n2.nabble.com/rawmessage-forwarding-doesn-t-appear-to-work-td7482747.html

With `%msg:2:2048%` the message part of the `syslog` event starts immediately.